# How to mount Ubuntu /home directory on ext4 partition in Windows 10 WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to mount my actual Ubuntu `/home` directory, which exists on an ext4 partition on my drive, to WSL.

Basically, I need everything from there, and I want to have better compatibility with ext4 and some tools.  Also see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/659) for some examples of problems when editing files in the existing WSL Ubuntu `/home` directory.

Is it possible? How?

Comment: My question is not about the github issue, but about mounting an ext4 partition (or a folder) as WSL `/home` folder.

Answer (score 1):

At the time this question was asked, this was not possible in WSL, as there was no access to *real* ext4 partitions.

However, the problems mentioned in that Github issue were resolved by providing access to the WSL (at the time WSL1, but subsequently also WSL2) filesystem through `\\wsl$\<distroname>\`.  This allows those files to be safely edited.  Also see the corresponding Microsoft blog post from around that time, [Do not change Linux files using Windows apps and tools](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/).

And, under Windows 11 (but not Windows 10), you now have the ability to mount raw drives into WSL2 using `wsl --mount`.  Once the raw drive is made available to WSL2, you can then `sudo mount` (or via `/etc/fstab`) the actual ext4 partition on that drive that contains your `/home/`.

Caveats:

- You must (currently) manually `wsl --mount` the raw partition *before* starting distribution (e.g. Ubuntu) in WSL.  If you don't, then you won't have a `/home` when starting WSL, and it will likely just fail.
- If I recall correctly, you cannot currently mount a drive which is already in use in Windows.  So the ext4 partition needs to be on a drive, at the least, other than the Windows drive.

Answer (score 0):

Export your home partition w/ Samba and mount that in Windows (that's how I do it).

To clarify, if you don't want to mount `/home` to a drive, then make
`/home` a symlink to `\\yourmachine\home` (assuming you've exported your home
drive as `/home`).

For example, I have `/Documents` pointing to `//Bliss/Documents` 
Under cygwin+bash, I see (in my root dir): `Documents -> //Bliss/Documents/`

In Windows, with `dir`, that file looks like: `<SYMLINKD> Documents [\\Bliss\Documents]` 
 (Bliss is a name for my server).

in Windows, I create that in root by cd'ing to root, then: 
 (from bash -- note single quotes around Windows pathname w/backslashes)

```powershell
cmd /c mklink /d Documents '\\Bliss\Documents'
```